# How to allow or passthrough a (re)invite in Freeswitch dialplan

Tags: sip, voip, freeswitch

In freeswitch dialplan I create a extension debug_001 and bridge to another freeswitch instance.

```
<extension name="debug_001">
         <condition field="destination_number" expression="^\+(49301234567)$">
            <action application="export" data="sip_invite_params=user=phone"/>
            <action application="export" data="sip_cid_type=pid"/>
            <action application="export" data="t38_passthru=true"/>
            <action application="export" data="sip_from_uri=${sip_from_uri}"/>
            <action application="bridge" data="sofia/gateway/FS2/$1"/>
         </condition>
</extension>
```

That works fine, the extension match in the right case and the call is bridged to FS2. But in case the FS2 instance  send a reinvite the FS1 instance do not bridge the (re)inivte to the caller. In the reinvite there is set a custom header field we want to parse on the Caller site.

Here is a ladderdiagram that show the SIP Flow.

[image: Ladderdiagram]

Or more detailed with this diagram:

[image: SIP Flow]

FS1 do not bridge the reinvite to the Caller. Maybe the reinvite was parse as a keepalive between FS1 and FS2 because nothing is change in SDP or something else, only the custom header ist inserted. What action I should define to passthrough the (re)invite in any case?

I think the problem is that Freeswitch only bypass the (re)invite if the SDP of the (re)invite was changed, in that case the SDP isnt diffrent and sofia indicate this as Duplicate SDP, as you can see here:

```
fac8529a-e0d9-11e8-91c6-0d38c130bd96 2018-11-05 10:05:46.508841 [DEBUG] sofia.c:7048 Channel sofia/external/49301234567 entering state [ready][200]
fac8529a-e0d9-11e8-91c6-0d38c130bd96 2018-11-05 10:05:46.508841 [NOTICE] sofia.c:8123 Channel [sofia/external/49301234567] has been answered
fac8529a-e0d9-11e8-91c6-0d38c130bd96 2018-11-05 10:05:46.508841 [DEBUG] switch_channel.c:3773 (sofia/external/49301234567) Callstate Change EARLY -> ACTIVE
fac8529a-e0d9-11e8-91c6-0d38c130bd96 2018-11-05 10:05:46.568848 [DEBUG] switch_rtp.c:7254 Correct audio ip/port confirmed.
fac8529a-e0d9-11e8-91c6-0d38c130bd96 2018-11-05 10:05:54.228841 [DEBUG] sofia.c:7048 Channel sofia/external/49301234567 entering state [received][100]
fac8529a-e0d9-11e8-91c6-0d38c130bd96 2018-11-05 10:05:54.228841 [DEBUG] sofia.c:7055 Duplicate SDP
fac8529a-e0d9-11e8-91c6-0d38c130bd96 v=0
fac8529a-e0d9-11e8-91c6-0d38c130bd96 o=- 1541408745 2 IN IP4 10.1.11.10
fac8529a-e0d9-11e8-91c6-0d38c130bd96 s=-
fac8529a-e0d9-11e8-91c6-0d38c130bd96 c=IN IP4 10.1.11.10
fac8529a-e0d9-11e8-91c6-0d38c130bd96 b=AS:64
fac8529a-e0d9-11e8-91c6-0d38c130bd96 t=0 0
fac8529a-e0d9-11e8-91c6-0d38c130bd96 m=audio 10374 RTP/AVP 8 101
fac8529a-e0d9-11e8-91c6-0d38c130bd96 a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
fac8529a-e0d9-11e8-91c6-0d38c130bd96 a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
fac8529a-e0d9-11e8-91c6-0d38c130bd96 a=ptime:20
```

So I need a solution to tell sofia send also duplicated SDPs or that Sofia also parse the custom header field in the (re)invite Header. In this [JIRA Ticket](https://freeswitch.org/jira/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/FS-6446/FS-6446.html) Brian West wrote that this behavior is a proxy Feature and Freeswitch isn't a proxy. But in our case the SDP is the same but the custom header field is diffrent so it isnt a Proxy Behavior and should be bypass to the diffrent Call-Leg.

Comment: Please paste the sip log. It will be good if you can provide the fs log also.

Comment: @suren I add more information to the question, it looks like FreeSWITCH do not understand this behavior because it is a proxy feature. Or is this information from the linked JIRA Ticket obsolete?